# I'm having trouble centering a cell of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, css

I'm generating an HTML table from an array of objects. If the signature is on the left, I need to put it in the middle. In case I have two signatures, I need to leave them centralized, as they already are.

My current code:

```
var result = [

                  {name: "John",
          jobPosition: "President"
                    },

                  {name: "Marc",
          jobPosition: "Director"
                    },

                    {name: "Paul",
          jobPosition: "Director"
                    },

                    {name: "Mary",
          jobPosition: "Director"
                    },

                    {name: "Carl",
          jobPosition: "Geral Secretary"
                    },
                        ];



var table = '<table style=" height: 94px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>';
    result.forEach(function(item, index) {
        
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            table += '<tr style="height: 35px;">';
        }
        table += '<td style="width: 50%; height: 150px; text-align: center; font-family: arial; font-size: 12pt;" valign="top"><p>_____________________________</p><p>' + item.name + '</p><p>' + item.jobPosition + '</p></td>';
        
        if (index % 2 == 1 || index == (result.length - 1)) {
            table += '</tr>';
        }
    });
    table += '</tbody></table>';
gs.info(table);
```

In this example,Carl's signature needs to come in the middle.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y00cX.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, only Carl's should be centred? I've run your code - all 5 look centered

Comment: Hello! I don't think I could explain it that well! When only one signature is on the left side, it should come in the middle. In the case of ending up with two signatures, it must be centralized, as the code is already doing

Comment: you'll need a `colspan` I guess - this sort of layout would be better using grid or flex I suspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excuse me sir. now i found out your desire.

you should add colspan attribute to te last td if index % 2 == 1
and set the amount of this colspan to 2

Comment: I think I couldn't explain it so well! When only one signature is on the left side, it should come in the middle. In the case of ending up with two signatures, it must be centralized, as the code is already doing

Comment: I added an image to illustrate better

Comment: excuse me! is my screenshote true result of your codes?and your result is different?

Comment: you should add colspan attribute to te last td if index % 2 == 1 and set the amount of this colspan to 2